# How to limit number of digits after decimal point in python random

Tags: python

I am using this code:`newAgent = [random.gauss(0, 1), random.gauss(0, 1)]`
and I want to limit the number of digits after decimal point.now is about 20 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple. Just use `round` and then specify the places with `, #Number of spaces`. In this example, I did to 5 decimal spaces.

```
import random
newAgent = [random.gauss(0, 1), random.gauss(0, 1)]
print(round(newAgent[0], 5), round(newAgent[1], 5))
```